# Select Where clause with specific date format?

Tags: php, mysql

My table have data structure like this

```
    cate_id  task_id   date_start              date_end                other
         34     14   2012-06-27 10:21:39    2012-06-27 10:21:42     Volume
         34     14   2012-06-27 10:21:42    2016-01-01 00:00:00     Volume




UPDATE tbl SET other ='new'
WHERE task_id =14 
AND cate_id=34
AND DATE_FORMAT('date_start','%Y-%m-%d')='2012-06-27' 
AND DATE_FORMAT('date_end','%Y-%m-%d')='2016-01-01';
```

My goal is only compare the date with format   '%Y-%m-%d' not whole the value.

Can do like the above mysql Script? Because it succeed executed sql script ,but does not update the col that I have specific? Anyone could tell me please? thanks

Comment: you have to compare only the date part, check that link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/10/sql-server-retrieve-select-only-date-part-from-datetime-best-practice/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hum...

Try removing the quotes around `date_start` and `date_end`:

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_start,'%Y-%m-%d')='2012-06-27' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_end,'%Y-%m-%d')='2016-01-01';
```

Comment: @user777297 Accepted is better word of action on SO than thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `date(date_start)` and `date(date_end)` instead of `date format`

```
UPDATE tbl SET other ='new'
WHERE task_id =14 
AND cate_id=34
AND date(date_start)='2012-06-27' 
AND date(date_end)='2016-01-01';
```

FYI: [function_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)